# How to change values in a column of a data frame based on conditions in another column?

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I would like to have an equivalent of the Excel function "if". It seems basic enough, but I could not find relevant help.

I would like to assess "NA" to specific cells if two following cells in a different columns are not identical. In Excel, the command would be the following (say in C1): if(A1 = A2, B1, "NA"). I then just need to expand it to the rest of the column.

But in R, I am stuck!

Here is an equivalent of my R code so far.

```
df = data.frame(Type = c("1","2","3","4","4","5"),
                File = c("A","A","B","B","B","C"))
df
```

To get the following Type of each Type in another column, I found a useful function on StackOverflow that does the job.

```
# determines the following Type of each Type
shift <- function(x, n){
  c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(6, n))
}

df$TypeFoll <- shift(df$Type, 1)
df
```

Now, I would like to keep TypeFoll in a specific row when the File for this row is identical to the File on the next row.

Here is what I tried. It failed!

```
for(i in 1:length(df$File)){
df$TypeFoll2 <- ifelse(df$File[i] == df$File[i+1], df$TypeFoll, "NA")
}

df
```

In the end, my data frame should look like:

```
aim = data.frame(Type = c("1","2","3","4","4","5"),
                 File = c("A","A","B","B","B","C"),
                 TypeFoll = c("2","3","4","4","5","6"),
                 TypeFoll2 = c("2","NA","4","4","NA","6"))
aim
```

Oh, and by the way, if someone would know how to easily put the columns TypeFoll and TypeFoll2 just after the column Type, it would be great!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop to use `ifelse` as `ifelse` is vectorized, i.e. `ifelse(c(head(df$File,-1)==tail(df$File,-1), TRUE), as.character(df$TypeFoll), NA)`

Comment: Thanks! Your code works, even though I still have to go through it to understand the logic!

Comment: I showed a vectorized way to get the same output you showed in `aim`

Comment: In your expected output it is not clear, where does the last TypeFoll (6) come from - it is not present in the initial data. Apart from that, `{dplyr}`s function `lead()` does exactly the same as your function `shift()`. This code should produce what you need: `library(dplyr);
df$TypeFoll2=ifelse(lead(df$File)==df$File,lead(df$Type),NA)`

Comment: I just added 6 in the shift function: rep(6, n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows (not keeping the result from the shift function)

```
df = data.frame(Type = c("1","2","3","4","4","5"),
                File = c("A","A","B","B","B","C"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# This is your shift function
len=nrow(df)
A1 <- df$File[1:(len-1)]
A2 <- df$File[2:len]
# Why do you save the result of the shift function in the df?
```

Then assign `if(A1 = A2, B1, "NA")`. As akrun mentioned `ifelse` is vectorised: Btw. this is how you append a column to a `data.frame`

```
df$TypeFoll2 <- c(ifelse(A1 == A2, df$Type, NA), 6) #Why 6?
```

As 6 is hardcoded here something like:

```
df$TypeFoll2 <- c(ifelse(A1 == A2, df$Type, NA), max(df$Type)+1)
```

Is more generic.

Comment: 6 was just for illustrative purpose (not so illustrative, I guess). I actually need NA! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First off, 'for' loops are pretty slow in R, so try to think of this as vector manipulation instead.

```
df = data.frame(Type = c("1","2","3","4","4","5"),
                File = c("A","A","B","B","B","C"));
```

Create shifted types and files and put it in new columns:

```
df$TypeFoll = c(as.character(df$Type[2:nrow(df)]), "NA");
df$FileFoll = c(as.character(df$File[2:nrow(df)]), "NA");
```

Now, df looks like this:

```
> df
  Type File TypeFoll FileFoll
1    1    A        2        A
2    2    A        3        B
3    3    B        4        B
4    4    B        4        B
5    4    B        5        C
6    5    C       NA       NA
```

Then, create TypeFoll2 by combining these:

```
df$TypeFoll2 = ifelse(df$File == df$FileFoll, df$TypeFoll, "NA");
```

And you should have something that looks a lot like what you want:

```
> df;
  Type File TypeFoll FileFoll TypeFoll2
1    1    A        2        A         2
2    2    A        3        B        NA
3    3    B        4        B         4
4    4    B        4        B         4
5    4    B        5        C        NA
6    5    C       NA       NA        NA
```

If you want to remove the FileFoll column:
    df$FileFoll = NULL;